# SAS %do %until loop

Tags: loops, macros, sas

As a part of my, loops need to be done until a condition is met. I am using the code as following:

```
%IF &maxvif ge &thresh %THEN

%DO %UNTIL (&maxvif lt &thresh)

....

%END;
```

However, it could not run properly. Even when &maxvif=4.05, it still says (&maxvif lt &thresh) is false. Thus, this loop never stop.

Below is part of the log, both macro variables are resolved properly, but the final evaluation went wrong.

> SYMBOLGEN:  Macro variable MAXVIF resolves to  4.050694277
>
> SYMBOLGEN:  Macro variable THRESH resolves to 10
>
> MLOGIC(BACKWARDVIF): %DO %UNTIL(&maxvif lt &thresh) condition is
>   FALSE; loop will iterate again.

Comment: I believe if you are comparing decimal numbers in a macro you need to use %evalf or %sysevalf.

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't work. Actually, before this %if-%then, there is another %if &maxvif lt &thresh %then %do. it evaluated the condition properly.

Comment: Sorry @LuYang but Reeza is correct.  Not only does it work but it is required for operations involving decimals in macro code.

Answer (score 2):

Your condition is being assessed as text.  In a text comparison "10" < "4.05" since "1" < "4", just like "AZ" < "BB" due to "A" < "B".

To flesh out @Reeza's comment, here is a sample macro that seems to work as expected.  It's a whole lot of `%sysevalf`:

```
%Macro testme(thresh,maxvif);
    %Do %until (%sysevalf(&maxvif > &thresh ));
        %Put "In Do Loop: maxvif= &maxvif -- thresh = &thresh";
        %Let maxvif = %sysevalf(&maxvif + 1);
    %End;
    %Put "--- DONE!   maxvif= &maxvif  -- thresh = &thresh";
%Mend;
```

`%testme(7,4.05123)` prints to the log:

```
In Do Loop: maxvif= 4.05123 -- thresh = 7
In Do Loop: maxvif= 5.05123 -- thresh = 7
In Do Loop: maxvif= 6.05123 -- thresh = 7
--- DONE!   maxvif= 7.05123 -- thresh = 7;
```

Comment: Thanks Tim！It works. I tried another way by using %sysfunc(int(&maxvif)), which also works. However, I'm confused because it can be evaluated properly in the %if-%then procedure, but not in %do-%until. Do you have any idea about it?

Comment: Hmmm. I couldn't reproduce that, so there may be something else going on in your code. Of course, if you put in values of 3 and 4.05 it will work as either a text or value comparison.

Comment: Hi Tim, you may find the code in my blog: http://lyangquant.weebly.com/blog/stepvif_incomplete